# Need help reshaping multidimensional NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

In TensorFlow, I have a Tensor, `h`, of shape `(?, 14, 14, 512)`.

I reshape by doing `tf.reshape(h, [-1, 196, 512])`

Which results in a tensor of shape `(?, 196, 512)`. Perfect. I need to do the same with a numpy array.

I have a giant multidimensional NumPy array saved to disk. It looks like this:

`features = numpy.ndarray([3000, 14, 14, 2048], dtype=np.float32)`

and need it to be of shape:

`[3000, 196, 2048]`

How can I do this transformation such that I do not lose information?

Would it be `numpy.reshape(features, (3000, 196, 2048))`?

Or `numpy.reshape(features, (-1, 196, 2048))`?

Do both of these methods of reshaping result in the same result or what is the difference?

Comment: You should get the same result, both with tf.reshape and np.reshape

Answer (score 1):

can be written as

```
a = np.ndarray([3000,14,14,2048])
b = a.reshape((-1, 196, 2048))
```

shape dimension can be -1 and the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

In your case the first value of the dimension has to be 3000 to fulfil the remaining dimensions.

> Do both of these methods of reshaping result in the same result or what is the difference?

these 2 should give you same result

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid and will give you the same result:

```py
features = np.ndarray([3000, 14, 14, 2048], dtype=np.float32)

# prints (3000, 196, 2048)
print(np.reshape(features, (3000, 196, 2048)).shape)

# prints (3000, 196, 2048)
print(np.reshape(features, (-1, 196, 2048)).shape)

# another option, prints (3000, 196, 2048) as well
print(features.reshape((-1, 196, 2048)).shape)
```

As long as you have exactly one `-1` dimension, numpy will be able to figure its value automatically.